# Binary coding of pairwise comparisons

Tags: r, matrix

I'm working on a questionnaire where there are always three statements presented at a time and participants have to rank order these according to their preferences (3 = most preferred, 1 = least preferred).

For further analyses I have to transform these rankings into pairwise comparisons within each block of three. Below is a code doing this for the first six items (2 blocks) of the questionnaire.

```
data <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1,3,3,1,2),2,6)

i1i2 <- ifelse(data[,1] > data[,2], 1, 0)
i1i3 <- ifelse(data[,1] > data[,3], 1, 0)
i2i3 <- ifelse(data[,2] > data[,3], 1, 0) 

i4i5 <- ifelse(data[,4] > data[,5], 1, 0)
i4i6 <- ifelse(data[,4] > data[,6], 1, 0)
i5i6 <- ifelse(data[,5] > data[,6], 1, 0)

result <- cbind(i1i2, i1i3, i2i3, i4i5, i4i6, i5i6)
print(result)
```

I extended this code to fit a 45 item questionnaire and it works fine. Now, I'd like to write a function which automatically does this job for n items. I experimented with while and for loops but couldn't succeed.

Can anyone please give me a hint/ reference to the relevant functions I need/ an example on how to do this?

Related: Brown, A., & Maydeu-Olivares, A. (2011). Item response modeling of forced-choice questionnaires. Educational and Psychological Measurement, 71(3), 460–502.

Comment: Your code returns all zeroes, is that intentional?

Comment: Do you have several "data" matrices, one for each participants? If yes, are all of them one-row matrices? If no, please show us the structure of the data for two participants. Please provide data of sufficient complexity (but still _minimal_) for your problem.

Comment: @Henrik: Sorry, you are right. I extended my example to two participants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, remove the `ifelse` and put them at the end instead:

```
i1i2 <- data[,1] > data[,2]
i1i3 <- data[,1] > data[,3]
i2i3 <- data[,2] > data[,3]
…
result <- ifelse(cbind(i1i2, i1i3, i2i3, i4i5, i4i6, i5i6), 1, 0)
```

Next, avoid unnecessary repetition.

```
three_way_compare = function (data, index) {
    cbind(data[, index + 0] > data[, index + 1],
          data[, index + 0] > data[, index + 2],
          data[, index + 1] > data[, index + 2])
}

result = ifelse(do.call(cbind, lapply(seq(1, ncol(data), by = 3),
                                      three_way_compare, data = data)), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

While there are probably more efficient alternatives, you could convert your matrix to a list of vectors of length 3 and apply the ifelse statements to them through a function.

**Update**:

If you have multiple rows in your matrix, you need to use `t(data)` inside `split()` to get the correct values.

```
# Put data in lists of 3
blocks <- split(t(data), ceiling(seq_along(data)/3))

# Define function
comparison <-function(x) {

i1 <- ifelse(x[1] > x[2], 1, 0)
i2 <- ifelse(x[1] > x[3], 1, 0)
i3 <- ifelse(x[2] > x[3], 1, 0) 

return(cbind(i1,i2,i3))

}

# Apply function to list
lapply(blocks,comparison)
# $`1`
#     i1 i2 i3
# [1,]  0  0  1
#
# $`2`
#     i1 i2 i3
# [1,]  0  1  1
#
# $`3`
#      i1 i2 i3
# [1,]  1  0  0
#
# $`4`
#     i1 i2 i3
# [1,]  0  0  1


# Or unlist to get vector
unlist(lapply(blocks,comparison))
# 11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33 41 42 43 
#  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1
```